# I worked on CANVAS HTML5 and now wanna do some 3D with webGL, how do I go about it?

Tags: html, canvas, webgl

Like I have mentioned in my question, I am pretty okay at working on the canvas element of HTML5 and have tried out some really cool "2D" effects with vanilla js and canvas drawing effects. But now I am kinda bored of this plus, I hate having to create most functions from scratch, then I saw some webGL examples, and I was completely blown away... A quick look at the source made me realize it was all Greek to me! =P

It would be great if you could point me to some really gr8 beginners resource to start working on webGL! I would appreciate it if it would have me avoid learning openGL for the purpose...

Answer (score 1):

[learning webgl](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/)

is the way to go. Begins actually with very few opengl things itself, but later you will not be able to avoid learning a good chunk of OpenGL (ES)